# OOP problems with instance variables

Tags: php, oop

I've got some problems with a piece of code in my two classes 'File' and 'Folder'. I've created a page which shows me the content of my server space. Therefore I've wrote the class Folder which contains information about it self like 'name', 'path' and 'children'. The children property contains an Array of 'Files' or 'Folders' within this folder. So it's a kind of recursive class. To get the whole structure of a wanted directory I've wrote some recursive backtracking algorithms that are giving me an array of objects for all children in the same structure as my folder on the server. The second algorithm is taking that array and searches an special folder. If it finds this folder the method will return the root path to it and if the folder isn't a subfolder of this directory the algorithm will return false. I've tested all of that methods for the 'Folder' object and it works just fine but now I've detected an error by using my script more intensive.

```
/**
 * find an subfolder within the given directory (Recursive)
 */
public function findFolder($name) {

    // is this object the object you wanted
    if ($this->name == $name) {
        return $this->getPath();
    }

    // getting array
    $this->bindChildren();
    $result = $this->getChildren();

    // backtracking part
    foreach($result as $r) {
        // skip all 'Files'
        if(get_class($r) == 'File') {
            continue;   
        } else {
            if($search_res = $r->findFolder($name)) {
                return $search_res;
            }
        }
    }

    // loop runned out
    return false;

}

/**
 * stores all children of this folder
 */
public function bindChildren() {
    $this->resetContent();
    $this->dirSearch();
}

/**
 * resets children array
 */
private function resetContent() {
    $this->children = array();
}

/**
 * storing children of this folder
 */
private function dirSearch() {
    $dh = opendir($this->path);

    while($file = readdir($dh)) {
        if($file !== "" && $file !== "." && $file !== "..") {
            if(!is_dir($this->path.$file)) {
                $this->children[] = new File($this->path.$file);
            } else {
                $this->children[] = new Folder($this->path.$file.'/');
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

In my website I first create a new folder object and then I'm starting to find a subfolder of 'doc' which is call 'test' for example. The folder 'test' is in '/var/www/media/username/doc/test4/test/' located

```
$folder = new Folder('/var/www/media/username/doc/');
$dir = $folder->findFolder('test');
```

If I print out `$dir` it returns a link as I wanted because the folder 'test' is a subfolder of 'docs' but the returned link is not correct. it should be '/var/www/media/username/doc/test4/test' but the result is '/var/www/media/username/doc/test' I've tried to debugg a bit and found out that the folders list which contains all children is keeping the objects with the right links but in the findFolder method in the first if condition the object `$this` doesn't have the correct path. I don't know why but the the

```
// backtracking part
foreach($result as $r) {
```

seems to change the object properties. I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. PHP already has a class for that purpose named `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php